# I'm struggling to retrieve a number from Firestore Firebase database in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie in firestore and Android Development, and I'm doing an app challenge.
In this app I need to store some quantities of items in a firestore database, to update them when i remove or add items in the app.

I wish to take a field in the document to set it as a variable, so I can do the maths in the function.

Here is the farthest that I could make:

```
fun getQuantity(name: String) {
        db.collection("Coin").document(name)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    val coinQuantity = document.getLong("quantity")
                }
            }
    }
```

```
val quantity100 = cent100.getQuantity("cent100")
var quantity100x = quantity100

// I have another 5 rows like this, one to each Brazilian Real coin
```

Document that I'm trying to read the quantity field from:

[image]

But it is not working, and I dont know what to try next...
The quantity100x is used in while loops to determine how many coins will be expended in a change, briefly talking.

Can anyone help me?

The repository: https://github.com/DaniloVolles/ChangeMachine.git

I have already tried the addOnSuccessListener and the aware functions to do it, but none of them worked.

In fact, I want to get a data from the db and pass it as a Long to a variable!

Comment: 0) What isn;t working about the code you shared? Is there an error message? 1) Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the document this code reads? 2) Did you check (in a debugger) whether the app reaches the `if (document != null) {` line? 3) Did you also attach an `addOnFailureListener` to catch/display errors?

Comment: 0) The val quantity100 cannot retrieve the number in the field "quantity".
1) Thank you, I'll surely make it!
2) I can't debbug it, because the function doesn't allow the return of the number. What you see in the "if" statement belongs to the if statement.
3) No, I didn't try it yet.

Comment: Your `getQuantity` doesn't return any value, so `quantity100` won't have a value after `val quantity100 = cent100.getQuantity("cent100")`. Even if you do add a `return` to `getQuantity`, it still won't work as data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290696/firestore-get-a-value-from-collection-field-then-return-kotlin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202#51595202

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Frank! I'll try these solutions!

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicates to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).